# Can I use spring batch writer to for both HTTP post request and write to db

Tags: java, rest, http, spring-batch, writer

I would like to read a list of records from DB, then iterate over it, and perform the following actions for each record:

1. Resolve data for generating JSON body, and send HTTP post request.
2. Update DB, according to the above HTTP post result.

I would like to use Spring-Batch framework on order to manage multi node sync.
Its it possible to use this framework ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `CompositeItemWriter` with two delegate item writers: one that sends the post request, and the other updates the DB.